# Partial Typing Destructured Object Parameters

Tags: typescript

Here is my typescript function:

```
function foo({
  a,
  b,
  c
}:{
  a, //delete this line?
  b, //delete this line
  c:number
}){
  //code deleted for simplicity
}
```

The function uses Destructured Object Parameters. The function also specifies the type for one of them `c:number`, but not for the other two `a` , `b`

my question is: is there a more concise way to write this function signature? perhaps by deleting the mentioned lines and replacing them with a generic definition?

Comment: That code is only valid with `implicitAny`. What type should `a` and `b` have?

Comment: @Behemoth the type should be any, the function works as it is, i just want make it more consice

Comment: Hmm, you could use an intersection of a `Record<PropertyKey, any>` (to represent any object) and `{c: number}`. That allows you to destructure any member with `c` still typed as `number`. Check out [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVJxwAoBvAKHnigBoL4AjWysWgelYD0B+OgDyfgBPAQC9aAXwBc8AErgcMYAB4ACjBwAHEDAyCA0iGFVUggHzwAZPBLww01MgC29bfHEBKaQDccWYAG4yIA).

Comment: brilliant, i implemented your idea with some [improvements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAHghgOxAXgEoQMYHsBOATAHgAUctIdQBpCEAGikRAD4AoAMwFcENgBLLBFDZYsACgDeLKA1pSoAI1nSMLAL4AueEigAyKOKhyAFhAA25dQg4BbeRByHVASknSA9G+x5o30xGAQeEK4UADOvNZgprwYvKBqQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of a `Record<PropertyKey, any>` (to represent any object) and `{ c: number }`. That allows you to destructure any member with `c` still typed as `number`.

```js
declare function foo({
  a,
  b,
  c,
//^? (parameter) c: number
  x,
  y,
  z,
}: Record<PropertyKey, any> & { c: number }): void;
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVJxwAoBvAKHnigBoL4AjWysWgelYD0B+OgDyfgBPAQC9aAXwBc8AErgcMYAB4ACjBwAHEDAyCA0iGFVUggHzwAZPBLww01MgC29bfHEBKaQDccWYAG4yIA)